# Creating a centered carousel with react-alice-carousel

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, frontend, carousel

I have struggled the whole day to create a centered carousel with react-alice-carousel library and the results are [those](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/82092907/163629857-8924ab56-54c3-40bf-834f-9863c1990d54.gif). Link to the library [here](https://github.com/maxmarinich/react-alice-carousel)

Basically I achieve the results showcased on the gif which were fulfilling enough for me but the fact that the focused image (the one on the left) is not centered is bugging me a lot. I have tried overwriting certain CSS properties but the results were not great (carousel item disappears if I try absolute positioning). My question is - is there a certain algorithm I can add to my logic so that the centered image would be in the middle of the carousel always? (2nd item in array of 3, 3rd item in array of 5, 4th item in an array of 7 and etc.) and if such algorithm does not exist how can I achieve to make my carousel centered-oriented.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-lichterman-knwbce?file=/src/App.js 
Targeted tile (plays the role of the product in my gif) is marketed in red color

Also mostly my carousel in the project:

```
 // Carousel helper properties / functions
  const responsive = {
    2000: {
      items: 11,
    },
    1200: {
      items: 5,
    },
    800: {
      items: 3,
    },
    0: {
      items: 1,
    },
  };
  const handleDragStart = (e: any) => e.preventDefault();
  const items = products.map((product, index) => (
    <img
      key={product._id}
      className={selectedIndex === index ? "focusedImage" : "shownImage"}
      onDragStart={handleDragStart}
      style={{ height: "150px", width: "150px" }}
      src={product.image}
      alt='Product that is being sold on this page'
    />
  ));
  return (
    <main>
      <div className='details__wrapper'>
        <AliceCarousel
          activeIndex={selectedIndex}
          mouseTracking
          responsive={responsive}
          items={items}
          infinite
          controlsStrategy={"default"}
          autoPlayStrategy='all'
          autoPlayInterval={1000}
          disableDotsControls
          disableButtonsControls
          keyboardNavigation
          onSlideChanged={(e: EventObject) => {
            setSelectedIndex(e.item);
            setSelectedProduct(products[e.item]);
          }}
        />
```

As seen all of the images that are seen by the user already have classes "shown" or "focused" image

And my SASS:

```
.alice-carousel {
  &__wrapper {
    & .alice-carousel__stage {
      &-item {
        z-index: 0 !important;
        & .shownImage {
          opacity: 0.5;
          margin: 0 auto;
          grid-area: image;
          display: block;
          border: 2px solid;
          border-radius: 50%;
          height: 20rem !important;
          width: 20rem !important;
        }
        &.__target {
          z-index: 1 !important;
          .focusedImage {
            opacity: 1 !important;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Mostly classes already listed in the documentation on GitHub.

Comment: The library you're currently using does not seem to support centering the carousal. I made an example with the "Swiper" library instead: https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-infinite-loop-with-slides-per-group-react-forked-j8jbf9?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Gave it a try and achieved the wanted result. Hopefully in the future they would add this function in the react-alice-carousel library. Have a good day sir!

Answer (score 1):

I've had luck adding `text-align: center;` to the `.alice-carousel` class.

```
.alice-carousel {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    direction: ltr;
    text-align: center;
}
```